# Making element border meet browser window on browser resize

Tags: css

As I shrink the browser screen, how can I make an element's border smoothly meet the edges of the window while text remains 15px away from the sides?

I have the following HTML:

```
<section>
 <header>
  <h1>Header Text</h1>
 </header>
</section>
```

In desktop view, it looks like this:

[image]

The section has a `max-width` of `1000px`, and it is centered with `margin-left` and `margin-right` set to `auto`. Furthermore, the header is `width:100%` (as is by default) and it has a `border-top:1px solid black;`.

In mobile view, the header looks like this:

[image]

So the `header` with the border on the top touches against the edge of the screen, but the `h1` inside has `15px` of padding on the left and right.

My question is: when the screen shrinks from 1030px to 1000px, how do I make it so that the h1 content always stays 15px away from the edge of the screen, but the border meets the edge of the screen?

```css
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
section{max-width:1000px;margin:0 auto;}
header{border-top:1px solid black}
@media(max-width:1000px){
  h1{padding:0 15px;}
}
```

```html
<section>
 <header>
  <h1>Header Text</h1>
 </header>
</section>
```

Comment: ...and media queries are not helping you because?? :)

Comment: I can't figure it out even with media queries

Comment: post the code you have done with media queries....would check and update it!

Comment: I posted some code at the bottom of the question, see it? The key is that the border has to smoothly meet the edges of the browser on resize but the text has to stop moving toward the side of the screen once it's 15px away from the edge of the screen.

Comment: I don't think you can have a `max-width` property set on your `section` element and achieve your desired result. You will have to set the `max-width` on your `header` element. Check out my answer and let me know if that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to position your `h1` element absolutely using a media query:

```
body{padding:0;margin:0;}
section{max-width:1000px;margin:10px auto;}
header{border-top:1px solid black}

@media (max-width: 1030px) {
  h1{position: absolute; left: 15px}
}
```

Here is the solution shown on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/robertcooper_rc/pen/NwVEdE).

Comment: Won't this make the border the full width of the screen though? I want the top border to have a max width of 1000px.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood what you wanted. Let me fix up my solution!

Comment: @NickManning check this solution out. If I understand correctly, this is what you're looking for?

Comment: Actually a really smart solution! Almost ready to accept your answer...but I intend for there to be text underneath the header, and applying position absolute takes the element out of document flow. Do you have any solutions for this?

Comment: Oh, that's a tricky one. You would have to wrap your `h1` element and any other text elements in a wrapper div and apply the `position: absolute` declaration to the wrapper element.

Comment: Okay...I managed to get it working by simply applying a fixed height to the wrapper. Good thing I know that the h1 won't span multiple lines though. It wouldn't work for that, but it works for me now. Great solution, thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)